# UIPageContro response time for Large numbers

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I have a UICollectionView and a UIPageControl in my program. When I test the app with an array that contain less than 1000 elements the response time and memory usage is acceptable.
But when I use an array with 2000 elements the response time will be 15 seconds. With 4000 elements 115 seconds and with 12000 elements, it takes about 50 minutes to respond and uses 3.5GB of memory. When the first page loads, the memory usage declines to 100 MB.

The issue persist at this line of code and commenting this line will solve the issue.
But this line is very important and I can't eliminate it.

```
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count
```

Why the response time and memory usage increase exponentially from 1000 to 12000 records and how should I handle large number of pages?

Comment: This is not good. The Array objects retains and brings the objects into the memory. You need to change the approach to load only the -2 n +2 pages from the current viewing page. This helps avoiding memory related Issues. Move to `Core Data` to achieve this.

Comment: The problem is just with the pageControl.

Comment: If I remove the mentioned line of code, the app uses 60 MB of memory and responds in less than a second

Comment: Then maintain a count variable yourself. Never call the `count` property.

Comment: The matter seems to be with pageControl pageindicator circles (they want to load in memory) , not the count property.

Comment: 1000 iems in array / 002 seconds response time/  50 MB memory

Comment: 2000 iems in array / 015 seconds response time/  55 MB memory

Comment: 4000 iems in array / 120 seconds response time/  65 MB memory

Comment: 12000 iems in array / 50 minutes  response time/ 120 MB memory ( it reaches to 3.5 GB befor the first page loads and when the first page loads, memory drops to 120 MB )

Comment: I created a single view application and put a UIPageControl and a UILabel on the view. I changed the UIPageControl number of pages property to 10000 and XCODE stopped responding and I had to force quit XCODE. I must find a way to divide UIPageControl number of pages by a number like what happens in iBooks and PDF viewer softwares

Comment: Why do you want to show UIPageControl in the first place. I checked the code, yes it is taking time to load all the views for UIPageControl i.e the dots, actually it is creating too many dots. Thats why iBooks uses the UISlider to handle this.

Comment: I need the pageControl.currentPage property. When I swipe to new page I use that control to perform a function. When a new page appears the pageControl.currentPage value changes and if an incomplete swipe happens, its value does not change. This is the reason why I need that control

Comment: I want to be informed of complete appearance of new page.

Comment: Can't you track using the UISlider is my base question.

Comment: I have not thought about that. I will try it.